# How to map a job among multiple workers using Redis Pub/Sub?

Tags: php, performance, redis, publish-subscribe

I have a Redis client which needs to split/map a job among say 3 workers. Suppose the job consists of 3 tasks. I want to map them in such a way that 3 of them runs in parallel and the job takes only (approx) 1/3 of execution time. Is there any way to do this with Redis itself? I didn't find any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use redis to create a task queue. For example, you can have a master process pushing tasks to a task queue and then have workers polling the task queue constantly for new work.

Master psuedo code:

```
while(1)
  if some_condition
    redis.rpush "tasks", "task1"
    redis.rpush "tasks", "task2"
    redis.rpush "tasks", "task3"
  end
  sleep 5
end
```

Worker pseudo code:

```
while(1)
  # blpop blocks until there is an element in "tasks" 
  task = redis.blpop("tasks", 0)[1]
  perform task
end
```

Comment: I would use `blpop` instead of `lpop` in the worker. `blpop` blocks until there is something on the queue, which avoid the busy-wait.

Comment: @Theo thanks for the tip! This simplifies the worker code quite a bit.

Comment: Thanks. I have asked this in redis list too. There are some answers that do not use Pub/Sub but are equally useful. http://groups.google.com/group/redis-db/browse_thread/thread/4554391e031060b6/f8559259cbca6505?lnk=gst

Comment: @mixdev Correct, this is not a pub/sub solution. I think you would only want to use pub/sub if *all* workers need to receive the same task when placed on the queue.  However, that did not seem to correspond with your use case.